# Story about two companies creating a program that adapts to the user's language

Tags: story-identification, books

It was story about two companies that were trying to create a special microphone/program that would adapt to the users language. One of the key characters was a genius kid that wrote code in machine language, but would not create any type of user manual. The main character was a programmer that wrote a simple version of an anti-virus program. This was back in the hey days before anti-viral programs were main stream. All of the programmers were working on MAC. Another part of the storyline was that a virus had been released to coincide with the release of the final product. The genius kid was also a private pilot.

I thought that the name of this book was "The Hacker and the Ant", but searching for that brings up a completely different story. I believe that "hacker" was in the title.

Comment: How old is the story? When did you read it? Was the book paperback or hardcover, American or British?

Comment: Was this a novel or a short story?

Comment: Rudy Rucker (who wrote The Hacker And The Ants) wrote a short story with a similar-ish title, "Chu and the Nants", though it doesn't sound like a match.

Comment: This has a lot in common (though also a lot not in common) with "Tyro" (https://qntm.org/tyro), the answer to one of the Related Questions.